# How to put div tiles float properly without gaps

Tags: html, css, css-float

In my web page i have some tiles. I want to show the tiles in two coloumns. After the first two tiles next two tiles should go right below it. As the height is variable i am not able to get it to work properly.

Here is what i got so far.

HTML:

```
<div class = "content" style="color:Red"> 
    <p> hi</p>
    <p> hi</p>
    <p> hi</p>
    <p> hi</p>
    <p> hi</p>
    <p> hi</p>
</div>
<div class = "content" style="color:green"> 
    <p> hi</p>
    <p> hi</p>
    <p> hi</p>
</div>
<div class = "content" style="color:black"> 
    <p> hi</p>
    <p> hi</p>
    <p> hi</p>
    <p> hi</p>
</div>
<div class = "content" style="color:blue"> 
    <p> hi</p>
    <p> hi</p>
    <p> hi</p>
    <p> hi</p>
    <p> hi</p>
    <p> hi</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
    border: solid 1px #C8C8C8;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px; 
    width :45%;
    height : auto;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top:20px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 0px #C8C8C8;
    cursor:pointer;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yKuBr/

Comment: do you want them to line up at the top or something because as far as I can see the bottom two are underneath the top two?

Comment: For what pattern are you aiming here? Two container in every row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a clearfix. a `div` element to clear all floats and start the flow over again.

http://jsfiddle.net/yKuBr/2/

Comment: With your change i see some gap between green and blue colours. I want to see all tiles with equal spacing. Is this possible

Comment: To be more clear in this link http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ assuming each color is div they are all equally spaced. i want to do that.

Comment: ah I see what you mean now, you could do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/yKuBr/3/ add the ones on the left and on the right to their own container

Comment: Yes this is the best method. If you want to have this all the same height I'd recommend simply using min-height. To make this work in IE I'd use the min-height fast-hack. He's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/MqTTy/1/

Comment: I honestly think that a CSS-only approach (such as the one in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15162365/313115) or in @xpy comment) is the best, simplest, and most elegant solution. You don't have to add useless elements in the DOM (hence you keep the separation between content/presentation), and you can handle it in a much simpler way should you add content dynamically, especially when you have to clear every two elements.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understood your question, but you might want to put a class on odd numbered tiles and `clear:left`. I updated your [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yKuBr/1/).

Comment: could also be `.content:nth-child(2n+1)` instead of additional class.

Comment: With your change i see some gap between green and blue colours. I want to see all tiles with equal spacing. Is this possible

Comment: To be more clear in this link http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ assuming each color is div they are all equally spaced. i want to do that.

Comment: @xpy `:nth-child` is certainly an elegant solution. It might take a bit more than this simple answer, though, to make it sufficiently backwards-compatible.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to create some kind of tiling, with containers of variable sizes, I strongly suggest using a great jQuery plugin called [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

Answer (score 1):

Remove **float:left** and add **display:inline-block**

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is `inline-block`:

HTML

```
<div class = "content ib" style="color:Red"> 
    <p> hi</p>
    <p> hi</p>
    <p> hi</p>
    <p> hi</p>
    <p> hi</p>
    <p> hi</p>
</div>
<div class = "content ib" style="color:green"> 
    <p> hi</p>
    <p> hi</p>
    <p> hi</p>
</div>
```

etc., etc. then in your CSS:

```
.ib {
    float:none;
    display:-moz-inline-stack;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

You can see a modified version of your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ultranaut/Us6vE/).

If you need to support IE6 or 7, you can trigger `hasLayout` by setting the `zoom`. If you want to find out more about it, there's a good article on it by [Robert Nyman](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/).

Answer (score 1):

This could be accomplished with [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/columns) columns, although [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn) is limited (i.e. no support in IE until IE10). See [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JDCD4/) or code below.

CSS

```
.content {
    border: solid 1px #C8C8C8;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px; 
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 0px #C8C8C8;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    width:95%
}

.cols {
    -webkit-column-count:2;
    -webkit-column-gap:10px;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="cols">
    <div class="content" style="color:Red"></div>
    <div class="content" style="color:green"></div>
    <div class="content" style="color:black"></div>
    <div class="content" style="color:blue"></div>
</div>
```